# Working with Future[Validation[E,A]] in for comprehensions

Tags: scala, scalaz

I want to change a few apis that return: `Validation[E,A]`, to be asynchronous, so ideally: `Future[Validation[E,A]]`. However I'd like to be able to use for comprehensions with these.

Consider the following example:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scalaz.{Failure, Success, Validation}

def getName : Future[Validation[Int,String]] = {
  Future{
    Success("ed")
  }
}

def useName(name:String) : Future[Validation[Int,String]] = {
  Future{
    Success(s"hi $name")
  }
}


val name : Future[Validation[Int,String]] = getName.flatMap{ v =>
  v match {
    case Success(name) => useName(name)
    case Failure(e) => Future(Failure(e))
  }
}

Await.result(name, 1.second)
```

To get `name`, I need to get the successful value from the validation, and call `useName` with that value.

Is there a way I can do something along these lines:

```scala
val name : Future[Validation[Int,String]] = for{
  n <- getName
  b <- useName(n)
} yield b
```

It's as if I'd like the comprehension to work in a `Future > Validation` context.

I'm happy to use slightly different types, and I have considered just using `Future` by itself with exceptions, but I'm curious to know if the above would be possible, without any blocking happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the only way would be to write your own `FutureValidation` monad:

```
case class FutureValidation[+E, +A](futval: Future[Validation[E, A]]) {
  def map[B](f: A => B)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): FutureValidation[E, B] = {
    val result = futval.map { validation =>
      validation.fold(
        fail => Failure(fail),
        succ => Success(f(succ))
      )
    }
    FutureValidation(result)
  }

  def flatMap[EE >: E, B](f: A => FutureValidation[EE, B])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): FutureValidation[EE, B] = {
    val result = futval flatMap { validation =>
      validation.fold(
        fail => Future(Failure(fail)),
        succ => f(succ).futval
      )
    }
    FutureValidation(result)
  }
}


object FutureValidation {
  def apply[E, A](validation: => Validation[E, A])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): FutureValidation[E, A] =
    apply(Future(validation))
}
```

And then you could have something like:

```
implicit val e = ExecutionContext.global

val a = scalaz.Success("")
val b = Future(scalaz.Success(""))

for {
  r1 <- FutureValidation(a)
  r2 <- FutureValidation(b)
} yield r2
```

Comment: If you want to `flatMap`, you're better off using disjunction, `\/`. And if you do that, then you can use `EitherT` instead of rolling your own.